# Why after extract zip by 7-zip, then all file come into root directory

Tags: command, 7zip

My zip file like this above:

```
D:\TEST.zip
```

and the Architecture in the zip is:

```
a.jar
lib
 └───b.jar
```

I use the following command to unzip file

```
7z e D:\TEST.zip
```

but I get this

```
a.jar
b.jar
lib
```

Why all the file are move into the root directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that is the default behavior for the command line extraction. You need to include a switch to keep the folder structure:

`7z e -r D:\TEST.zip`